Convex combination of linear dependent vectors
Suppose a collection of vectors $\mathbf{a}_1,\cdots, \mathbf{a}_n\in\mathbb{R}^m$ are given, where $n>m+1$. Those $\mathbf{a}_1,\cdots, \mathbf{a}_n$ are surely linear dependent.
Let $\mathbf{y}$ be a convex combination of $\mathbf{a}_1,\cdots, \mathbf{a}_n$, i.e.,
$$
\mathbf y=\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i\mathbf{a}_i, ~\text{for some } \alpha_i\geq 0, \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i=1.
$$
Can we show that there exist a subset $\{l_1,\cdots, l_{m+1}\}\subset\{1,\cdots,n\}$, with $l_i\neq l_j$ for all $i\neq j$, such that
$$
\mathbf y=\sum_{i=1}^{m+1} \beta_i\mathbf{a}_{l_i}, ~\text{for some } \beta_i\geq 0, \sum_{i=1}^{m+1} \beta_i=1.
$$
It is easy when we consider the affine combinations, i.e., with constraints $\alpha_i\geq 0$ and $\beta_i\geq 0$ removed.  In the affine case, we can use the trick
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{y}\\
1
\end{bmatrix} = \sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_i 
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{a}_i\\
1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
to make sure $\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i=1$ and prove the statement by the property of linear dependent. But how to deal $\alpha_i\geq 0$ and $\beta_i\geq 0$ in the convex combination case?
Thanks in advance.

Carathéodory's theorem answers this question.

Thanks! Follow Wikipedia, I found the proof of Theorem 3.3.10 in this book is what I want.
